# You're a large automobile

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, cryptic-clues, geography

> 1. Capital city says you're a large automobile (7)
> 2. Work horse videography camouflages monastery (9)
> 3. Football stadium building hides coastal city (6)
> 4. Black Sea hub hides Caspian Sea hub (4)
> 5. Mountain lake hears a number (5)
> 6. Capital city in stabilisation (7)
> 7. Continent's roof is confused rubles (6)
> 8. Black Sea city is British nasal sound in silicon (7)
> 9. Volcano is heartless Kazakh and Uzbek (6)
> 10. Short Greece, magical land and US metropolis pronounce foul patella (6)
> 11. Confused sheik inside sheep skin (5)
> 12. *Morgan Jackson* conceals narcotic substance (5)

Where are we?
<sub>Edit: Rewrote part of the 12th clue (in *cursive*) in response to comments.</sub>

Comment: There's a construction you've used in several of your clues lately, where you say "in X" or similar to mean that some set of letters are taken from X, in order but not necessarily consecutively. The usual convention is that this sort of extraction is always done consecutively. (I'm trying to think how one would indicate your sort, but I'm not sure I've ever seen it in a cryptic crossword.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Ok thanks, I'll keep that in mind. Still learning how to formulate these...

Comment: To be fair, @jafe’s sort are usually significantly harder than consecutive, but I do agree that I don’t normally see that in cryptics. They’re fun as heck though!

Comment: Rewrote the 12th clue to better fit the puzzle format.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
1   Capital city says you're a large automobile (7)
```

> Yer a  <strike>wizard</strike>  van, Harry — YEREVAN, capital of Armenia.

```
2   Work horse videography camouflages monastery (9)
```

> As found by @NudgeNudge, this refers to worK HORse VIdeogRAPhy hiding KHOR VIRAP, a monastery.

```
3   Football stadium building hides coastal city (6)
```

> footBAll sTadiUM buildIng yields BATUMI, Georgia, coastal capital of the autonomous region of Adjara.

```
4   Black Sea hub hides Caspian Sea hub (4)
```

> BlAcK sea hUb hides BAKU, Azerbaijan, a Caspian Sea hub.

```
5   Mountain lake hears a number (5)
```

> Lake SEVAN in Armenia is the largest lake in Armenia and in the Caucasus region.

```
6   Capital city in stabilisation (7)
```

> sTaBILISatIon hides the capital of Georgia, TBILISI.

```
7   Continent's roof is confused rubles (6)
```

> Confused rubles yields ELBRUS, the tallest mountain in Russia.

```
8   Black Sea city is British nasal sound in silicon (7)
```

> Ukhum in Si yields the Black Sea city of SUKHUMI, capital of Abkhazia.

```
9   Volcano is heartless Kazakh and Uzbek (6)
```

> Kazakh and Uzbek - Akh and uz = KAZBEK, a volcano in Russia.

```
10  Short Greece, magical land and US metropolis pronounce foul patella (6)
```

> GR + OZ + NY = GROSSKNEE = GROZNY, the capital of Chechnya.

```
11  Confused sheik inside sheep skin (5)
```

> Sheik mixed up and SHEepsKIn yields SHEKI, Azerbaijan.

```
12  Morgan Jackson conceals narcotic substance
```

> morGAN JAckson hides GANJA, a slang term for cannabis and also a city in Azerbaijan.

It looks like you are in

> The former Soviet Union. @snetch finds that more specifically, we are in the Caucasus Mountains. Thanks, @snetch!

Comment: All of those are more specific to the Caucasus mountains, not the entire Soviet Union.

Comment: I believe 2 is rot13(Xube Ivenc).

Comment: There's a better fit for #5, something that's located in the same geographical area as the rest of the answers. Also note that I've rewritten part of #12.

Comment: @jafe how do 5 and 12 look now?

Comment: Yup, all correct now! Nice work.

Comment: Thanks! Fun puzzle, @jafe. Love these cryptic geography puzzles!